# Pods for microservice are not scheduling

Tags: openshift, persistent-volumes

I am trying to deploy a microservice on an Openshift shared cluster. This is my first time working in this environment.

When deploying to the environment I get the following error:

```
0/28 nodes are available: 25 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind, 3 node(s) had taint, that the pod didn't tolerate
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MeSW.png)

This is our value.yaml file:

`workerNodeSelector: - key: is_worker value: 'true' edgeNodeSelector: - key: is_worker value: 'true' workerTolerations: - key: is_worker operator: Equal effect: NoSchedule value: 'true' edgeTolerations: - key: is_worker operator: Equal effect: NoExecute value: 'true'`

What could be the cause of this issue?
Please help me if anybody has any idea.

I am unable to use these commands as well,

```
oc get pv,   
oc get pvc -n <namespace>,  
oc get nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

If we read through your error we see the following:

"3 node(s) had taint, that the pod didn't tolerate" This is pretty normal. It's just saying that it won't run your microservices on the control plane. Reasonable for a 28 node cluster.

"25 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind" This is your real error. Essentially your micro service cannot allocate storage on any of the nodes. You'd have to post your micro service YAML for specifics. But in most environments you aren't going to create a PV directly, they are going to be dynamically created by storage classes. Either something you are asking for is incompatible with those storage classes, you don't have permission, or they don't exist.

So what do you do to fix it?

- Either remove the requirement for storage
- Change the requirement for storage to something that can be supplied (say moving from RWX to RWO if only RWO is available)
- Ask the cluster admin to either create a storage class that matches your needs (or allow you permissions to one that exists)

Querying for a list of storageclasses that are available might be a good first step.

Comment: Thank you @David Ogren for the detailed explanation about the issue and its solutions. Will start with storage classes as you mentioned.